# Google Vision API performance

Tags: google-vision

Am trying to OCR around 50,000 documents(~20K size jpegs). Currently using a homegrown tesseract based solution but are looking to migrate to google vision for better accuracy

Based on quotas published at https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas
my calculation is

**600 requests/min with upto 16 images per request will give us a throughput of 9600 OCRs per minute.**

Has anyone done any bulk operations using google vision? We did some POCS where some of these bulk requests are taking ~5mins.

Comment: These quotas are related to making requests, but the time for getting **response** depends entirely on the document which has been uploaded.

Comment: @MohammedJamali Thanks for response. The fact is I am sending exactly the same document and the degrading response is confusing a decision on the systems scalability.